# Python selenium press ctrl + v at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> at the same time on selenium chromedriver, I tried a lot of different combinations, like `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'V')` or very similar things. Nothing worked. I'm working on WIndows 10

Comment: can you show the entire code? because element.send_keys() should work

Comment: just use small letter v and your code will work

Comment: @PDHide no, it does the same, only writes v instead of paste

Comment: which browser are you using

Comment: @PDHide I'm using google chrome with chromedriver

Comment: it should work perfectly i added an example , just try runnign that code . You should add proper waits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs of the Selenium ([The Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys)), This is the solution for Control+C:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

You can just exchange the 'c' key by 'v' and it should work
you can possibly add the element you trying it to insert into by changing `keys.CONTROL` to `keys.CONTROL, element`

Comment: do you mean like `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL, element).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL, element).perform()`

Comment: i assume so, im not 100% sure on that exact part, i assume you can delete the element from the second bracket, since releasing is not element specific. instead i would add it to the bracket with ('v')

Comment: Should I import something special?

Comment: Probably this : from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! Here is how it worked `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL, element).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL, element).perform()
`

Comment: You are just over complicating it

Comment: Well at least it works, and as long it works its fine imo, there are multiple ways to achieve something

Comment: @Timeler thats why we need code review for :D you can make it work with 5 loops or in single line.

Comment: Well the thing is the other solutions might look better, i completely see that, but they did not work according to the guy who asked, so i provided another method, sometimes you are just glad that it finally works, even tho you could possibly make the other solution work as well

Comment: for Mac use `Keys.COMMAND`

Answer (score 1):

use small letter v:

both answers will work:

```
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
```

Eg:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\prave\\Downloads\\travelBA\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "c")
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys("test")
time.sleep(3)

elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: The above example types pycon then copys it and then change text to test and then pastes pycon and replaces test

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `,`

```
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'V')
```

Comment: It writes V instead of paste what I have copied